# mvaayoo api issue for sending messages from a website

Tags: asp.net

i am using mvaayoo api for sending the messages from my website.

i have read the documentation and do the same even then i am not able to send the messages.

i am using this sample code

```
string strUrl =  "http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose?user=
Username:Password&senderID=mVaayoo&receipientno=919849558211&msgtxt=This is a test from mVaayoo API&state=4"; 
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(); 
Stream s = (Stream)response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader( s );
string dataString = readStream.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
s.Close();
readStream.Close();
```

Help me please

Thanks,
Rajbir

Comment: Do you receive any error message?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of the space in URL.

Use this for URL ;

```
string strUrl =  "http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose?user=
Username:Password&senderID=mVaayoo&receipientno=919849558211&msgtxt=This%20is%20a%20test%20from%20mVaayoo%20API&state=4";
```

I replaced all space with %20 in the URL.  I suffered with the same problem in java.. so it should work..